# Arduino:upload resets `c_cpp_properties.json` in VSCode, causing include error

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, include, intellisense

I'm trying to get the `HelloWorld.ino` tutorial to work in VSCode+Arduino on MacOS. The project works fine when uploaded from Sketch––the `LiquidCrystal` library is listed as installed.

But in VSCode, Intellisense reports the library as not found:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

If I edit `c_cpp_properties.json` to add the last line as shown below, Intellisense can find the library.

```
# .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
"includePath": [
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/mega",
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include",
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include-fixed",
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include",
                "/maker-stuff/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/**"
            ],
```

However, when I do a `Arduino: upload`, the `c_cpp_properties.json` file is reset to the default. And while the project upload is "successful", the project does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the library manually, press `ctrl+shift+P` and type in "Arduino: Rebuild Intellisense Configuration" while you have the include at the top of your file. It stays after that and uploading should be fine. I'm not sure why manually adding the library doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you mate, this was driving me crazy. Thankfully you can disable auto-generation of Intelli sense configuration, i.e, rewriting of "cpp_properties.json", by turning off the setting within the Arduino extension.

1. Go to VS Code extensions tab. Click on the gear icon next to the Arduino extension and select "Extension Settings".
2. Uncheck "Arduino: Disable Intelli Sense Auto Gen"